# Is it possible to get rid of these shading artifacts for a smooth shaded flat surface?

Tags: modeling, artifacts

I am modeling a logo and want beveled edges that will be smooth shaded to look rounded but a flat surface that looks flat do you have any sugestions? 
This is the result after beveling edges:

[image]

Comment: You have to improve the topology of your logo. It looks like you have a single n-gone front face which should be split/optimized. This will give you more control on the bevel as well as prevent weird shading caused by the sharp induced triangles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper Topology

Having a proper topology depending on the kind of work you are doing solves this problem

as here blender doesn't have enough info to shade the front face correctly

you can check the CGCookie guide for clean topology [here](https://cgcookie.com/articles/guide-to-clean-topology)